# how to avoid Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: in monodroid

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android

i am using following codes

to create database oncreate

```
 private void chech_database_exist_or_not()
    {

        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "validation.db3");
        bool exists = File.Exists(dbPath);
        if (!exists)
            SqliteConnection.CreateFile(dbPath);
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath);
        connection.Open();
        if (!exists)
        {
            // This is the first time the app has run and/or that we need the DB.
            // Copy a "template" DB from your assets, or programmatically create one.
            var commands = new[]{

      "CREATE TABLE [user_detail] (_id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,user_name varchar,pass varchar,designation varchar,email varchar);",

    "insert into user_detail(user_name,pass) values('testuser','testpass') "


            };
            foreach (var command in commands)
            {
                using (var c = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    c.CommandText = command;
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        connection.Close();


    }
```

on button click i call below function

```
    private  bool validate_user(string username, string password)
    {
        bool i;
        i = true;
        string str;



        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string dbPath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "validation.db3");

        SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath1);
        str = "select pass from user_detail where user_name='" + username + "' and pass='" + password + "'";
        SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(str, con);
       // SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter(cmd);

        FillDatatable(cmd, dt);






        if (dt != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                i = true;

            }
            else
            {
                i = false;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            i = false;
        } 

        return i;

    }
```

following classes i use

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.OS;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Android.InputMethodServices;
```

can anyone help why i am getting this error and how i overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329593/system-entrypointnotfoundexception-on-sqldataadapter-fill-method):

> Unfortunately Android's SQLite library doesn't include support for the
>   sqlite3_column_origin_name() method, so any parts of Mono.Data.Sqlite
>   that depend on it are going to fail. Xamarin has a bug tracked
>   [here](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2128) for modifying the implementation to get around the
>   limitation, but there's no timeframe on it yet as far as I know.

The code in the question doesn't include the implementation of `FillDatatable()`, but I'm guessing that calls `DataTable.Fill()`, which is known to have this problem. The workaround for now is basically just to avoid using the parts of ADO.NET that depend on this missing functionality in Android, such as `DataTable.Fill()`.

Comment: so which database you prefer to use?

Comment: You can still use SQLite, which is the only database that ships on Android devices by default. The problem isn't that SQLite isn't supported, it's that the *version* of SQLite Android includes doesn't support certain operations used by the Mono provider. You can still use ADO.NET, just not all of it. This post might help you get started: http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-a-database-in-monodroid-applications/

Comment: i am still getting problem.  Can i have any sample project showing connectivity from sqlite in monodroid?

Comment: Yeah, just look at the link in my last comment :)

Comment: i am getting problem in the helper class